# Verilog : Combining sequential logic with combinational logic

Tags: verilog, multiplier

[image: Sequential Multiplier]

I am trying to implement a sequential shift and add 4bit multiplier as shown in the image.

I am having a separate module for the 4 bit ripple carry adder. I have tested the adder module and it works fine.

now i need to trigger it from the multiplier module. so that it triggers on the 'add' signal.
please help in modifying the ripple carry adder code i have included the code for reference

main module code which does not compile since i have included the rca4bit module inside the sequential always block

```
    `include "rca4bit.v"
module seq_mult_4bit(output [7:0]product,input [3:0]a,b,input clock,input reset,input start);
    //reg prod[7:0];
    reg multiplicand[3:0];

    parameter WAIT_STATE = 0, LOAD_STATE = 1, ADD_STATE = 2,SHIFT_STATE = 3;

    always @ (posedge clock) 
    begin
        if (reset)
            state <= WAIT_STATE;
        else
            case (state)
                WAIT_STATE:
                    if(start)
                        state = LOAD_STATE;
                    else
                        state = WAIT_STATE;

                LOAD_STATE:
                    //load data into registers
                    product[3:0] = 4'h0;//load accumulator with zeros
                    multiplicand[3:0] = a[3:0];
                    product[7:4] = b[3:0];
                    //read lsb
                    if(product[7] == 0)
                        state = ADD_STATE;//only add if there's a 1 in the multiplicand
                    else
                        state = SHIFT_STATE;//else move to shift state directly

                ADD_STATE:
                    //add the partial product
                    rca_4bit adder(product[3:0],c_out,multiplicand[3:0],product[3:0], 0);//adder block

                SHIFT_STATE:
                    product = {c_out,product[7:1]};
                    count = count + 1;
                    if(count == 3)//wrap around
                        count = 0;
            endcase
    end 
end module
```

//state machine

module code for ripple carry adder

```
`include "fulladder.v"

module rca_4bit(output [3:0]sum,output c_out,input [3:0]a,b,input c_in);

wire c1,c2,c3;

full_adder fa1(.in_x(a[0]),.in_y(b[0]),.c_out(c1),.sum_out(sum[0]),.c_in(c_in));
full_adder fa2(.in_x(a[1]),.in_y(b[1]),.c_out(c2),.sum_out(sum[1]),.c_in(c1));
full_adder fa3(.in_x(a[2]),.in_y(b[2]),.c_out(c3),.sum_out(sum[2]),.c_in(c2));
full_adder fa4(.in_x(a[3]),.in_y(b[3]),.c_out(c_out),.sum_out(sum[3]),.c_in(c3));
endmodule
```

please help!
PS:i am new to verilog so please excuse my noobness :)

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than addressing the many problems in your source code, let me just show how I'd implement the module you describe.

First, I wouldn't use a sub-module to build the adder; synthesis tools are perfectly able to create adders from behavioral code. Secondly, an elaborate state machine isn't required; the module can simply produce a final result four clocks after each activation of the `start` signal. I've added a `done` signal to the module interface to make this explicit.

```
module seq_mult_4bit (
  output  [7:0] product,
  output        done,
  input   [3:0] a,
  input   [3:0] b,
  input         clock,
  input         start
);

  reg     [7:0] product;
  reg     [3:0] multiplicand;
  reg     [3:0] delay;

  wire    [4:0] sum = {1'b0, product[7:4]} + {1'b0, multiplicand};

  assign done = delay[0];

  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (start) begin
      delay = 4'b1000;
      multiplicand = a;
      if (b[0]) begin
        product <= {1'b0, a, b[3:1]};
      end else begin
        product <= {1'b0, 4'b0, b[3:1]};
      end
    end else begin
      delay = {1'b0, delay[3:1]};
      if (product[0]) begin
        product <= {sum, product[3:1]};
      end else begin
        product <= {1'b0, product[7:1]};
      end
    end
  end

endmodule
```

If you really want to use an external module for the adder (which is really the point of your question), simply substitute the wire declaration above with the following block of code:

```
  wire   [4:0] sum;

  rca_4bit adder (
    .sum        (sum[3:0]),
    .c_out      (sum[4]),
    .a          (multiplicand),
    .b          (product[7:4]),
    .c_in       (0)
  );
```

Let me know if you have any specific questions about how this implementation works.

Answer (score 2):

First, in Verilog an instantiated module is always considered "combinatorial" logic even if it contains sequential logic inside it. For the purposes of the module that contains it, it's just a black box with inputs and outputs, so the containing module considers it combinatorial. That means the outputs of an instance are declared as `wire`s.

Second, in Verilog sequential logic happens within always blocks. Anything that's assigned to inside an always block will be declared as a `reg`. The only way for (physically) sequential logic to happen inside an always block is on the right-hand side of an assignment statement.

So you just need to move your instance outside the always block.

Here's a much simplified fragment:

```
module demo(clk, in, out)
   input clk;
   input in;
   output out;

   wire some_result;
   reg some_state;

   always @(posedge clk) begin
       case (some_state) 
           1'b0: begin
               out <= 1'b0;
               some_state <= /* calculate next state */
           1'b1: begin
               out <= some_result;
               some_state <= /* calculate next state */
        endcase
   end

   my_module inst0 ( .IN(in), .OUT(some_result) );
endmodule
```

With this structure, the output of the instance is available to the state machine, but the instance itself is instantiated outside the always block.

If you are trying to save power by having the instance only operate when it needs to, you can give the lower-level module an ENABLE input, and generate a signal in the state machine to control that input. However I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you really know you need to save power and that disabling the lower-level module will significantly reduce power consumption.